# Custom hostnames?

Tags: hostname

Say I owned a domain name i.e. `abc.com`, and I have the dns for this domain pointed to my static ip:

What steps would I need to take in order for a webserver to see that my hostname was userxyz.abc.com rather than userxyz.current_isp.com? (If such a thing is even possible).

Comment: Are you asking about reverse-IP resolution, so when someone/something looks up where you are connected from it returns your domain instead of that of your ISP?

Comment: Yep thats right

Answer (score 1):

You need an "A" or "CNAME" record for any name you wish to be publically resolvable to.  Also, in order to *be* the DNS provider for your domain, you need to setup a nameserver record that point to your DNS server.  Ultimately, you'll need at least 1 A record which has your IP in it... and as many CNAME records to point to any sub-domains that point back to your A record.

for example:

if you have abcd.com you'll need a minimum of 3 records at the root to make "abcd.com" resolveable.

1. SoA record - this record says you are the "Start of Authority" for this domain.
2. NS record - this record says what server is used to resolve names for this domain
3. A record - this is the actual record used to associate a name with an IP.

From there you can have sub-domain records as you see fit.

Online tools like "nwtools.com" can be useful to figure out what DNS records can be resolved.  It would also be useful to know what sort of DNS server you are running (Bind 9? Microsoft DNS? etc..)

Answer (score 1):

The only people who can do this are your ISP.  They control the reverse-DNS for your IP address.

If you have a static IP address from them they may be willing to change the DNS entry to suit you - you'd have to contact them to find out.